# How to make blocks of unit tests in R?

Tags: r, unit-testing

I have started to make unit-tests for my functions in R, using svUnit ([docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit/svUnit.pdf)). I have done the test for the functions in a file, then for the ones in another file, and I have created a mainTest, where I call all the tests. So my project looks like this:

```
proj
 |-src
 | |-functions1 (containing some functions)
 | |-functions2 (containing some other functions)
 | |-functions3 (containing some more functions)
 | |-mainFile (here I call the functions in the files above)
 |-tests
   |-functions1Test (containing tests for functions in functions1 file)
   |-functions2Test (containing tests for functions in functions2 file)
   |-functions3Test (containing tests for functions in functions3 file)
   |-mainTest (containing the function that runs all the tests)
```

a functionsXTest file looks like this:

```
source('functionsX.R')

test(fun1) <- function(){
   # call the fun1 function and check the result
}


test(fun2) <- function(){
   # call the fun2 function and check the result
}

# ...

functions1Tests <- svSuite(svSuiteList()) # here
```

The mainTests looks like this:

```
library('svUnit')

source('functions1Tests.R')
source('functions1Tests.R')
source('functions1Tests.R')

launchTests <- function(){
   clearLog()

   runTest(functions1Tests)
   runTest(functions2Tests)
   runTest(functions3Tests)

   Log()
}
```

I thought that the last line at the end of the file functionsXTest.R is grouping the unit tests in a variable, but it seems that it is grouping all the tests in that variable, so functions1Tests is containing the tests for all the functions in functions1.R, and functions2Tests is containing the tests in functions1.R and functions2.R. Is there a possibility to have all the tests in a file grouped in a variable and the run the tests on each variable, so it will be easier to find the problematic test?

Comment: I suggest the `testthat` from Hadley Wickham. I guess it will give you all the options you need. Such as context and messages which of your test failed.  [testthat](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html)

Comment: Nice testthat, but my svUnit is displaying enough info, but I wanted to group the test, so test first block, then the second, etc. Right now, they are all mixed, and I am sure that I have omitted something. If I cannot find it, maybe I'll propose testthat for unit tests to my superior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if I add the names of the tests in `svSuite`, it is separates the different tests, so doing:

```
functions1Tests <- svSuite("fun1", "fun2")
```

on the last line of the functionsXTest.R file, functions2Tests will not contain the tests for functions1Test.R.

But now I am wondering if there is a possibility to split the test in the Log, because now it will display something like:

```
> launchTests()
= A svUnit test suite run in less than 0.1 sec with:

* testfun1 ... OK
* testfun1 ... OK
* testfun2 ... OK
* ...

== testfun1 (in runitfunctions1Test.R) run in less than 0.1 sec: OK
//Pass: 7 Fail: 0 Errors: 0//

== testfun1 (in runitfunctions2Test.R) run in less than 0.1 sec: OK
//Pass: 4 Fail: 0 Errors: 0//

== testfun2 (in runitfunctions1Test.R) run in less than 0.1 sec: OK
//Pass: 10 Fail: 0 Errors: 0//
...
```

Comment: My problem is how to separate the tests so they will be displayed by groups: `testfun1, testfun2, testfun3 (in runitfunctions1Test.R)` then `testfun1, testfun2, testfun3 (in runitfunctions2Test.R)` etc